# ssh hangs when logging into virtual box

Tags: networking, ssh, fedora

I have 2 systems. On ubuntu, I setup nat or bridged network and I can ssh into debian-based system running in virtual box. When I do the same in fedora 33, the ssh command hangs.

I don't understand network sufficiently, so I just tried to disable fedora-firewall (systemctl stop firewalld) and flushed iptables (iptables -F), but still cannot connect.

What can still stand in a way / what can I try to find out what is happening?

Comment: At which point does it hang? Try `ssh -v -v` for a start, but also a packet capture (tcpdump/wireshark) on both systems.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It was hanging up right after verification of entry in .known_hosts. When I was trying to re-run it again, I noticed, that I cannot even log in to localhost and it hangs up. Same behavior as with virtualbox, just as the data arent reaching destination. It was long not restarted machine, so I restart it and now it works. Totally no idea what it could have been, "sadly" I cannot reproduce it any more. Totally puzzled what could lead to it. sshd was running, I checked. Thanks for you help, but I guess it's resolved eventhough the reason is unknown.